# Question about printing multiple items in a list in a specific order in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I've been racking my brain on this for a while and decided to reach out to you fine folks. The issue I'm trying to figure out is how to print items in a list in a specific order. I have a list:

```
m= ['dog','cat','horse','cow','woof','meow','neigh','moo']
```

And I want to have my results look like this:

```
'The dog goes woof'
'The cat goes meow'
'The horse goes neigh'
'The cow goes moo'
```

So far I have tried the following code:

```
m= ['dog','cat','horse','cow','woof','meow','neigh','moo']

for i in m[:4]:
    print('The ' + i + ' goes ' + str(x for x in m[4:]))
```

My results are:

```
'The dog goes <generator object <genexpr> at 0x01177C70>'
'The cat goes <generator object <genexpr> at 0x01177C70>'
'The horse goes <generator object <genexpr> at 0x01177C70>'
'The cow goes <generator object <genexpr> at 0x01177C70>'
```

Now I found out that the 'x' statement just returns a 'None' value which is why I don't get the results I want. Can anyone give me some insight? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you already know how to print the elements in the desired order (as seen by the animal names). Your problem is that you wrap your elements into a generator – why do you do that? What do you think ``str(x for x in m[4:])`` means? Also, is there any reason why you store animals and sounds in ``m``, instead of separating them into two lists or using a ``dict`` to map from animal to sound?

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi. My understanding of generators, in this instance, is limited... hence why I reached out to the community.The reason why I didn't create two list is because I wanted to see how I can print elements in a list in a particular order. The only reason why I used the words in 'm[]' is because they make sense to people. I appreciate and feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `zip` through list:

```
m = ['dog','cat','horse','cow','woof','meow','neigh','moo']

for x, y in zip(m, m[4:]):
    print(f'The {x} goes {y}')

# The dog goes woof
# The cat goes meow
# The horse goes neigh
# The cow goes moo
```

For any length list, you can do:

```
for x, y in zip(m, m[len(m)//2:]):
    print(f'The {x} goes {y}')
```

Comment: Love this Austin! I've never used 'zip' before so I will make an effort to learn more about it. Thank you greatly!

Comment: With those `{}` you can make it as readable as English. For ex: `f'The {animal} goes {cry}'`

Answer (score 3):

The expression `(x for x in m[4:])` is called a generator expression and is an object that can generate things, probably not really what you want.

This will solve your problem:

```
m = ['dog','cat','horse','cow','woof','meow','neigh','moo']

for i in range(4):
    print('The ' + m[i] + ' goes ' + m[i + 4])
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a list or array is generally to hold homogenous data -- if you have animal names and animal noises, those are distinct and the data structure should distinguish them.

e.g. split your list into two lists, and zip those into a list of pairs

```
m= ['dog','cat','horse','cow','woof','meow','neigh','moo']
for pair in zip(m[:4], m[4:]):
  print(f"the {pair[0]} goes {pair[1]}")
```

Though Austin's "for x,y" below is more idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

Harcoding is fine, but go with generic design by splitting it in two parts:

```
m= ['dog','cat','horse','cow','woof','meow','neigh','moo']
for pair in zip(m[:len(m)/2], m[len(m)/2:]):
  print(f"the {pair[0]} goes {pair[1]}")
```